# I have installed Node exporter on 100 different servers and reading data collected on my prometheus server. but unable to distinguish data

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a distributed system consisting of 100s of devices which has node exporter installed on them. My main server has a prometheus server which scrapes all these data. How do I know which data is coming from which of the devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define in your `scrape_configs` from `prometheus.yml` file different a `label` with the same name and different values for each node exporter

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'nodeexporter-01'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ 'nodeexporter:9100' ]
        labels:
          instance: 'nodeexporter-9100'
  - job_name: 'nodeexporter-02'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ 'nodeexporter:9200' ]
        labels:
          instance: 'nodeexporter-9200'
```

then you will see the `metric` like this:

```
metric{instance="nodeexporter-9100"}     X
metric{instance="nodeexporter-9200"}     Y
```