# How to add custom labels to the exposet mysql-exporter metrics?

Tags: prometheus

I am using [mysql-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/mysqld_exporter) to expose metrics.

Is there a way to add custom labels to the exposed metrics?

I have few environment variables like environment name, cluster name, hostname which I will like to be part of each metric.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can add custom labels from the `prometheus.yaml` config file as it is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730802/2096986